# Similarity score for mixed (binary & numerical) vectors

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, data-mining

I have a dataset which the instances are of about 200 features, about 11 of these features are  numerical (integer) and the rest are binary (1/0) , these features may be correlated and they are of different probability distributions ,

It's been a while that I've been for a good similarity score which works for a mixed vector and takes into account the correlation between the features,

Do you know such similarity score?

Thanks,
Arian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerous types of distance measures, [Euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), [Manhattan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), etc are going provide different levels of accuracy depending on the dataset. Best to read papers covering your method of data fitting and see what heuristics they use. Not to mention that some methods require only homogeneous data that scale accordingly. [Here](http://fedcsis.org/proceedings/fedcsis2012/pliks/347.pdf) is a paper that talks about a whole host of measures that you might find attractive.

And as always, test and cross validate to see if there really is an impact from the mixing of feature types.

Comment: Do you know any statistical package which works well with similarity scores and have many of them ?

Comment: Matlab has a large number of measures, if you have access to such an expensive program. Otherwise I'm sure google would be your friend here.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, the similarity function relies heavily on the input data patterns. You might benefit from learning a distance metric for the input space of data from a given collection
of pair of similar/dissimilar points that preserves the distance relation among the
training data.

[Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~liuy/frame_survey_v2.pdf) is a nice survey paper.

Comment: Actually why I want to define a similarity measure is because I want to do cluster for down sampling ! so it's not possible to learn it from the data

Comment: You don't need to have labeled data to learn a distance metric. Manifold learning and Kernel Methods are both examples of those methods.